# How do I use the Counter class with pandas groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

Given this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,3],[2,4]], columns = ['A','B'])
df
    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   2   3
3   2   3
4   2   4
```

I want to try different collections of aggregating values in B using `groupby` on column A and `apply` on column B

This works as expected if I collect B's as a **list**:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).reset_index(name='list')
    A   list
0   1   [1]
1   2   [2, 3, 3, 4]
```

This works as expected if I collect B's as a **set**:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(set).reset_index(name='set')
    A   set
0   1   {1}
1   2   {2, 3, 4}
```

I (naively) would have expected the Counter class to just work the same way:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([2, 3, 3, 4])
Counter({2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```

But it behaves rather unexpectedly when trying to use **Counter** the same way I used **set** or **list**:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(Counter).reset_index(name='counter')
A   level_1 counter
0   1   1   1.0
1   1   2   NaN
2   1   3   NaN
3   1   4   NaN
4   2   1   NaN
5   2   2   1.0
6   2   3   2.0
7   2   4   1.0
```

I was hoping for:

```
    A   counter
0   1   Counter({1: 1})
1   2   Counter({2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```

One interesting clue is this:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(type).reset_index(name='type')
A   type
0   1   <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1   2   <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

But this works as I would expect:

```
Counter(pd.core.series.Series([2, 3, 3, 4]))
Counter({2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```

And this doesn't work:

```
def mycounter(series):
    return Counter(list(series))
mycounter
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(mycounter).reset_index(name='type')
A   level_1 type
0   1   1   1.0
1   1   2   NaN
2   1   3   NaN
3   1   4   NaN
4   2   1   NaN
5   2   2   1.0
6   2   3   2.0
7   2   4   1.0
```

I kind of suspect a bug with Pandas?

(ADDED): I just tried this and it works.  So, I'm not sure why `apply` doesn't but `agg` does:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg([Counter]).reset_index()
A   Counter
0   1   {1: 1}
1   2   {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

Comment: You want `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(Counter).reset_index(name='counter')` `apply` is an interesting function, as it can both produce aggregated and non-aggregated results.

Comment: Basically a series is pretty much a dict, and a Counter is a dict. When you call `.agg()` it expects a single value as return thus it doesn’t try to re-expand it. Anyways to perform the same operation as Counter, in pandas you can use `value_counts()`

Comment: It's because `Counter` objects are `dict`s

Answer (score 4):

See [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate)

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(Counter).reset_index(name='counter')
```

```
   A             counter
0  1              {1: 1}
1  2  {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

---

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-apply) is an interesting function, as it can both produce aggregated and non-aggregated results.

Run:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3})
```

```
A   
1  0    1
   1    2
   2    3
2  0    1
   1    2
   2    3
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

When a `dict` is returned from `apply` it interprets the keys as indexes to the DataFrame. As opposed to interpreting it as an aggregated value (like with `agg`).

Hence why counters are interpreted like:

```
A   
1  1    1.0  # {1: 1} (index 1 value 1)
   2    NaN
   3    NaN
   4    NaN
2  1    NaN
   2    1.0  # {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1} (index 2 value 1)
   3    2.0  # (index 3 value 2)
   4    1.0  # (index 4 value 1)
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

---

However, with `agg` there is a single value expected to be returned so `dict` is interpreted as a single unit:

Run:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3})
```

```
A
1    {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
2    {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
Name: B, dtype: object
```